# Trying to setup a new notification for updating user password in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

So I'm trying to send a customized notification when the user is updating their password. The SendPasswordResetEmails.php file is in the vendor folder and as far as I'm aware I'm not supposed to directly modify the code there since it can be changed in updates and what not. So I made a controller called ChangePasswordController.php and copy pasted some of the methods in SendPasswordResetEmails.php for sending reset link email.

In my new controller, I have the following:

```
/**
 * Send a change link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function changePassword(Request $request) {
    $request['email'] = Auth::user()->email;
    $request['update'] = true; // user wishes to update/change their password

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink( 
        ['email' => Auth::user()->email] 
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
{
    return back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return back()->withErrors(
        ['email' => trans($response)]
    );
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker();
}
```

In the changePassword method, notice the line in sendResetLink:

```
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink( 
    ['email' => Auth::user()->email] 
);
```

How can I make a custom method sendChangeLink instead of the sendResetLink? I don't quite understand how $this->broker() part works so I don't want to mess with it but maybe someone here can help.

Comment: **SendsPasswordResetEmails** is a trait, you can override any method, no need to copy whole file https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords. If you only want to change mails, run **php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail** and update mail markdown in **resources/views/vendor/mail** folder. - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#customizing-the-components

Comment: I'm not trying to override the method. I'd like to extend it plus change the email and how it's handled. I need to make some customizations because I need more functionality than what's provided.

Since SendsPasswordResetEmails is in the vendor folder could you show me an example of how I would go about extending it? Like, what folder should I create the new class in? I read through the documentation but it's unclear to me how I would go about this.

Comment: Do want to change the mail markup?

Comment: I'd like to change the mail markup in addition to more functionality. I'd like to do it right and not just hack it. The mail markup isn't my biggest concern though, that part is relatively easy. Basically I'd like to have a password broker with new methods. It's unclear to me how to set this up.